# Python Error , IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

Everytime i try to execute this script, i get an Error.
Code:

```
def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/CHANNEL_NAME", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
    global numberOfSockets
    global numberOfViewers
    while True:
        if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
            numberOfSockets += 1
            print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
            urls.append(getURL())
```

Error:

```
  File "sript.py", line 19
    return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the second line of `getURL` so that it lines up with the return-statement:

```
def getURL(): # Get tokens
    output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/CHANNEL_NAME", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url']
```

Remember that Python takes indentation seriously since it uses it to determine what goes with what.

Comment: Well , that brings me to this Error:    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: Ahh i added the requests package and now it works fine! Thanks alot

Comment: @Downvoter - Could you at least leave a reason why you downvoted?  My answer solved the OP's problem.  What is wrong?